# Big doubts about Stash Bundle

Tags: stash, get

I try to understand better Stash Bundles, so I tried to use Stash code to save a group of variables as a single variable in a defined bundle.

**The variables:**

```
{exp:stash:set_value name="un" bundle="default"}
{exp:stash:set_value name="deux" bundle="default"}
{exp:stash:set_value name="trois" bundle="default"}
```

**The group of the variables inside a defined bundle:**

```
{exp:stash:bundle name="bundle"}
        {exp:stash:get  name="un"}
        {exp:stash:get  name="deux"}
        {exp:stash:get  name="trois"}
{/exp:stash:bundle}
```

**Call the defined bundle**

```
{exp:stash:get name="bundle"}
```

**Results (in the html page):**

```
a:3:{s:2:"un";N;s:4:"deux";N;s:5:"trois";N;}
```

**Why the variables appears like this, and not display:**

```
un
deux
trois
```

What it means **a:3:{s:2:** **;N;** ? I'm totally lost. How to display only **un deux trois**?

Thanks.

**Additional information.**

I tried with:

> http://site/stash/bundles

```
    {exp:stash:bundle name="segments"}
            {exp:stash:get name="{segment_1}"}
            {exp:stash:get name="{segment_2}"}
    {/exp:stash:bundle}

   <h1>{exp:stash:get name="segments"}</h1>
```

Results:

> a:2:{s:5:"stash";N;s:7:"bundles";N;}

So **a** is the number of variables into a bundle, **S:** the number of characters of each variables. What is **N** ?
I do not understand this output format, it seems as JSON. What can I do with this output:

**a:2:{s:5:"stash";N;s:7:"bundles";N;}** ?

How to use it, and **only** extract **stash**, **bundles** data, coming from {segment_x} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you are confusing bundles with **lists**. Stash lists will provide the functionality you're looking for (which is basically to group variables into an array). Bundles are merely used as a way of tagging variables and/or lists so they can be cache-busted independently.

Follow the examples in the documentation for `set_list`: https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3Astash%3Aset_list%7D

... and `get_list`:
https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3Astash%3Aget_list%7D

Comment: Hi James. Thank you for your explanation. Yes, there was a confusion between bundles and lists. Now I understand better, but why bundles give this results: a:2:{s:5:"stash";N;s:7:"bundles";N;} . How to process this output format ?

Comment: The format you're seeing is a serialized array. You won't ever need to process it manually. Use `get_list` and it processes it for you. You were seeing it because you were trying to output an array directly instead of its children

Comment: Thanks a lot James for your good explanation , now my doubts are gone :). Regards, Stéphane